# How to get the min of each row in PySpark DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to calculate min of each row in PySpark DataFrame.

In NumPy, it can be write

`df.min(axis=1)`

but I don't know how to do the same thing in PySpark DataFrame.

e.g. 
I create dataframe (my real data is approx. 1,000,000rows * 1,000cols):

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(10, 10, 1 ), (200, 2, 20), (3, 30, 300), (400, 40, 4)], ("c1", "c2", "c3"))


+---+---+---+
| c1| c2| c3|
+---+---+---+
| 10| 10|  1|
|200|  2| 20|
|  3| 30|300|
|400| 40|  4|
+---+---+---+
```

and I want output below:

```
+---+---+---+---+
| c1| c2| c3|min|
+---+---+---+---+
| 10| 10|  1|  1|
|200|  2| 20|  2|
|  3| 30|300|  3|
|400| 40|  4|  4|
+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: pls add the code and sample dataframe

Comment: Thanks, I add code.

Comment: AFAIK, there is not direct way to achieve this. If you create a table with values of 1000 columns into one, then there is a chance with UDF.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot!